# Change background colour of some text within textview programmatically only

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

How can I change the background of some text within my view programmatically only using as few lines of code as possible? I tried to use the background tag within the html but unfortunately it doesn't support that hence is there any possible workaround to achieve something like the image below?

**XML**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/main_textView0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"/>
```

**Java**

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = getView();

    TextView txt = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.main_textView0);
    txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#0099CC'>" + getResources().getString(R.string.hello) + "</font>" +
                    " " +
                    "<font color='#000000'>" + getResources().getString(R.string.world) + "</font>"
    ));

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

[image]

Comment: The HTML way is probably the only solution in this case.

Comment: i suggest you to use https://android-arsenal.com/ site which having library for it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/text/Spannable.html), something like:

```
            String str1 = "Hello";
            String str2 = "world";
            String message = str1 + " " + str2;

            Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(message);
            spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE),0, str1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            textView.setText(spannable);
```

Comment: Correct, then do the same thing with a BackgroundColorSpan.

Comment: @BladeCoder What about setting the foreground colour for str2? Do I simply add it underneath or do I need to add another Spannable?

Comment: I assumed str2 has the default text color of the TextView. You can select it with TextView.setTextColor()

Comment: @BladeCoder It's not a good idea to use that if all text will be in 1 textview. Can't I use another spannable.setSpan?

Comment: Yes you can but you don't need to for the portions showing the default text color and size.

Comment: @BladeCoder The word "world" is not in the default colour. I want the foreground colour of it to be black within the spannable. How can that be achieved?

Comment: The exact same way used in the above code. You just need to change the color and the Span position.

Comment: @BladeCoder I'll be using other languages for these strings hence is there a way of avoiding the use of span positions as words in different languages are not the same character length? That's why I'm using strings for this.

Comment: @MacaronLover That's more complicated indeed and would require a new question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is called from the UI thread (as it should be) but the call to *Html.fromHtml(...)* is very very expensive.
You can do it better by wrapping a couple of TextViews together in a LinearLayout and set each of separately. It might not look nicer in first look but it much easier to maintain and saves cpu.
Especiallyif you intend to use this is a recyclerview or something.